# Pseudo element: proper z-index stacking context?

Tags: css, z-index

I have two `DIV` elements on the same level: **bar** and **nav** with `::before` pseudo element.

That **nav** and **bar** should appear under `::before` pseudo element but text within **nav** above it, something like this:

```
|- nav text
   |- nav pseudo element
      |- bar
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  position: relative;
}
.bar {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
.nav {
  background-color: orange;
}
p {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.nav::before {
  z-index: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 40%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4rem 4rem 0 0;
  border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="bar">bar that should remain under green</div>
  <div class="nav">
    <p>text that should appear above green</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the same properties to text.

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  position: relative;
}
.bar {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
.nav {
  background-color: orange;
}
p {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.nav::before {
  z-index: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 40%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4rem 4rem 0 0;
  border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="bar">bar that should remain under green</div>
  <div class="nav">
    <p>text that should appear above green</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: It works! Why is `position: relative` so important here?

Comment: You cannot set z-index if you have not set any position rule. This happens because the natural position for all elements is somewhere where they don't overlap other elements so that z-index is not required where the default non-overlapping position is chosen.